# Custom button "Mark as Complete and New" on Phone Call form or other activity form in CRM 2013

Tags: button, customization, ribbon, dynamics-crm-2013

Sometimes there is a need to have one button which will automatically complete  and create a new phone call where some data from the old one are transfered to new one, there is a solution. It is also possible to implement this behaviour on other forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download the **Visual Ribbon Editor for CRM 2011/2013** from ​http://crmvisualribbonedit.codeplex.com/
2. Create **​Phone Call Ribbon Scripts** which will be used by button created in later steps.

[image: WebResource Script]

3. Define the following source of the script created in previous step. The script mark as completed the phone call and open a new phone call - regarding and description fields are sent through url. Therefore the url has to be shortened if it exceeds 2000 chars, otherwise the link does not work.

```js
function SaveAsCompleteAndNew() {
    // Attempt to save Activity and Mark it as Complete
    SaveAsCompleted();

    // If the form is not valid
    if (!Xrm.Page.data.getIsValid())
        return;

    var url = "/main.aspx?etn=phonecall&pagetype=entityrecord&extraqs=";

    var regardingString = "";
    var regardingValue = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("regardingobjectid").getValue();
    if (regardingValue != null) {
        regardingString += "&regarding_id=" + regardingValue[0].id;
        regardingString += "&regarding_name=" + regardingValue[0].name;
        regardingString += "&regarding_type=" + regardingValue[0].entityType;
        regardingString = encodeURIComponent(regardingString);
    }
    var descriptionValue = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("description").getValue();
    var descriptionString = ((descriptionValue != null) ? encodeURIComponent("description=" + descriptionValue) : "");

    // The url length is limited to about 2k chars, otherwise the link cannot be opened. Therefore the length has to be limited.
    var maxDescriptionLength = 1970 - (url.length + regardingString.length);

    if (descriptionString.length > maxDescriptionLength) {
        var shortenedText = descriptionString.substr(0, maxDescriptionLength - 25);

        // Patt1 checks if it ends with e.g. %1 and patt2 with %. These are not allowed because they have been reduced by 
        // substr. Correct format is three chars like %20 for white space. If there are not in correct format, url does not work
        var patt1 = new RegExp("%\\d$");
        var patt2 = new RegExp("%$");

        if (patt1.test(shortenedText))
            shortenedText = shortenedText.substr(0, shortenedText.length - 3);
        else if (patt2.test(shortenedText))
            shortenedText = shortenedText.substr(0, shortenedText.length - 2);

        descriptionString = shortenedText + encodeURIComponent("\n...shortened...");
    }

    var extraqsEncoded = descriptionString + regardingString;

    window.open(url + extraqsEncoded);
}
```

4. Run **Visual Ribbon Editor for CRM 2011/2013**, connect to CRM instance, select the Phone Call entity and add a new button "Complete And New" through New button fucntion. Define the following setting on the **Details** tab:

[image: Details Tab]

**Note**: As you can see there are also icons defined. Load these icons as web resource to the CRM.

5. Select **Action** tab and define the action which should be perfomed on click command of "Complete And New button". As a Function Name use the same name as defined in step 3. Library should be a path to the script created also in step 3.

[image: Action Tab]

6. You can also define **Display Rules** - in our case we show the button only to people who has right to write to the current phone call entry and also if the phone call is in **Open** status (statuscode = 1).

[image: Display Rules Tab]

7. Save all changes in **Visual Ribbon Editor for CRM 2011/2013** and publish them. Also do not forget to publish changes in CRM customization otherwise added webresources are not available.

Comment: `SaveAsCompleted();` is not a supported method.